# How to update AWS lambda's $LATEST to a previous version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can I update the **$LATEST** version of a lambda to a previous one, including all configurations?

Exporting the lambda version and uploading it, indeed update the code but not all configurations, e.g., Layers, File systems, etc.

Comment: are you looking for [`update-alias`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-alias.html#update-alias)?

Comment: I look for the **$LATEST** to be like one of the previous versions. not to update the alias

Comment: Ah so you're trying to downgrade LATEST to a previous version e.g. LATEST goes from v4 to v3?

Comment: Right, with all configurations of V3

Comment: You shouldn't use $LATEST then - create another alias for the version that you need and assign it to the version that you need. $LATEST will always point to the latest Lambda version, there's no way around that.